# Replace the performance function of a Neural Network

Tags: neural-network, matlab

i'm trying to replace the performance function of a neural network with my implementation.

i created a file:

```
function perf = MyPerformanceFunction(e, x, pp)

a = struct('regularization',0, 'normalization','none', 'normalize',0);

perf = a
```

and added

```
net.performFcn = 'MyPerformanceFunction';
```

to my NN

but when i run the NN, i got an error message:

```
    Error using feval
Undefined function or variable 'MyPerformanceFunction.normalize'.

Error in nncalc.setup1 (line 81)
  calcHints.perfNorm = feval([net.performFcn,'.normalize']);

Error in network/train (line 280)
  [calcMode,calcNet,calcData,calcHints,net,resourceText] =
  nncalc.setup1(calcMode,net,rawData);

Error in nntest3 (line 36)
net = train(net,Xs,Ts,Xi,Ai);
```

what did i do wrong?

thanks

Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way is to start with the current mse.m file and tweak it from there.